# Querying for Facebook Page's Messages without getting all messages ever

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-page, facebook-messages

I'm developing an application that directs messages from a Facebook page to a proprietary chat queue, however, I only want to get new messages (since the last time I retrieved messages).  I cannot find anywhere on the Internet that explains how to filter a Graph API query, and I am not able to figure out how to query for page messages using FQL.